# Find bases of the kernel $\phi:M_{2\times 2}(R)\to M_{2\times 2}(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to extract a kernel base of this linear application $\phi:M_{2\times 2}(R) \to M_{2\times 2}(R)$, where $\phi(X) = XB-BX$;
$B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

After some calculations I get: $\phi(\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
b-c & a-d\\
d-a & c-b
\end{bmatrix}$

I extract a standard base:
$$\phi(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\phi(\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\phi(\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\phi(\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
But once I get here I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: You have seen what $\phi$ does to the standard basis matrices. Can you construct the zero matrix from those results in any non-trivial way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} \longmapsto \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \\ d\end{bmatrix}
$$
is an isomorphism $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)\longrightarrow \mathbb R^4$. Under this isomorphism your map $\phi\colon M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)\to M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ corresponds to the map $\phi'\colon \mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^4$ given by
$$
\phi'\left(\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}b-c\\a-d\\d-a\\c-b\end{bmatrix} =
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} 0&1&-1&0 \\ 1&0&0&-1 \\-1&0&0&1 \\ 0&-1&1&0\end{bmatrix}}_{A} \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Compute the kernel of the matrix $A$ like you are used to and then translate it back to a subspace of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ by splitting $4$-vectors into $2\times 2$-matrices again.

Comment: After solving the system i get: $s(-1, 0, 0, 1), t(0, 1, 1, 0)$ but it is not clear to me how to proceed to write as matrices.

Comment: The vector $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ is not in the kernel $A$, you must have made a mistake in your calculation.

Comment: One basis of $\operatorname{ker}(A)$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Applying the inverse of the isomorphism above, these correspond to the two matrices $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ that form a basis of $\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the $\ker\phi=\{X\in M_{2\times2}(\Bbb R)\mid\phi(X)=0\}$. And, if $X=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then\begin{align}\phi(X)=0&\iff\begin{bmatrix}b-c&a-d\\d-a&c-b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\\&\iff a=d\wedge b=c.\end{align}So,$$\ker(\phi)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,a,b\in\Bbb R\right\}.$$Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

> After some calculations I get: $\phi(\begin{bmatrix}
> a & b\\
> c & d
> \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
> b-c & a-d\\
> d-a & c-b
> \end{bmatrix}$

Now what you need is to find a basis for the solution space of the following system of linear equations in the unknown $a,b,c,d$:

\begin{align}
b-c=0\\
a-d=0\\
d-a=0\\
c-b=0
\end{align}

But the third and the fourth equations are redundant, and any solution can be written as
$$
(a,b,c,d)=(a,b,b,a)=a(1,0,0,1)+b(0,1,1,0).
$$

Now you can write the result in terms of matrices.